# viewing rgb and depth from kinect camera in ubuntu 10.10

Tags: kinect, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't get any data (rgb image,depth image,rviz) from the kinect,I'm running on Ubuntu 10.10 ,diamondback;basically what I did is :

1. I set up my computer to accept software from ROS.org
2. I ran roscore on a new terminal by typing : roscore

3)I installed openNI kinect by typing : sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-openni-kinect

4)I installed openNi camera by typing : rosmake openni_camera

5)I launched the openNI driver by typing :roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch

6)I ran rviz by typing: rosrun rviz rviz

7)I ran the rgb camera by typing : rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color

please help me fix it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11676/viewing-rgb-and-depth-from-kinect-camera-in-ubuntu-10.10/) by [bassim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1280/bassim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-10-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bassim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1280/bassim/) on 2011-11-04**:
I got them from ROS.org ,if you think that they are wrong,could you please tell me what are the right instructions ?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-10-25**:
Where did you get these instructions from?  These are not the standard wa to install the kinect drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you would like to view images coming from the kinect camera, follow the instructions posted here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect and here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera

which are summarized as follows:

1. **install openni_kinect:** sudo apt-get install ros-electric-openni-kinect
2. **run openni:** roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
3. **run image viewer:** rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color

This video tutorial for the TurtleBot might also be helpful:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot/Tutorials/Looking%20at%20Camera%20Data

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-11-07**:
you should see a line like this in the output ... [ INFO] [1320711146.846538470]: Number devices connected: 1

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-11-07**:
can you copy and paste the output from that terminal into your question

**Comment by [bassim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1280/bassim/) on 2011-11-07**:
no , I didnt get any error !

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-11-04**:
are there any errors in the terminal where you called roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch?

**Comment by [bassim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1280/bassim/) on 2011-11-04**:
when I typed on a new terminal : rostopic hz/camera/rgb/image_color     .  I got this : WARNING: topic [/camera/rgb/image_color] does not appear to be published yet

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-11-04**:
@bassim do you see any errors in the terminal when you roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch .. can you rostopic hz /camera/rgb/image_color

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-11-02**:
@bassim what happens when you follow these instructions. do you see any console output? Any error messages? You need to provide more information so that we can help you

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, pasting half of the web into your question doesn't help.

What's this KinectROSPackage thing you're talking about? You should just install `openni_kinect` from the binaries:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-openni-kinect
```

and then use the various nodes it provides.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-10-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1